# Make Phone number clickable responsive

Tags: php, html, phone-number

adapting a theme for a website , there is a nice top head bar with a phone number on the top right but I d like it to be clickable when people browse it on their mobile, could you help me on this ?

```
 $phone = isset( $ct_options['ct_contact_phone_header'] ) ? esc_attr( $ct_options['ct_contact_phone_header'] ) : '';
```

Comment: Post more code and be more specific about your question.

Comment: There's this *crazy litte thing called* [**href**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html). Let's call it *love*.

Comment: Have you tried putting your question title in for example a search engine?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that array holds just the phone number...

```
? '<a href="tel:'.esc_attr($ct_options['ct_contact_phone_header'].'">'.esc_attr($ct_options['ct_contact_phone_header'].'</a>'
```

alternatively you can do it outside of your ternary when you actually echo out the $Phone variable..

```
echo '<a href="tel:'.$phone.'">'.$phone.'</a>';
```

Also, why just clickable on mobile? Some people want to click on their computer to call from Skype, or Google.